# Como escrever em arquivos, sem apagar o seu conteúdo?

Tags: java, arquivo

Como posso escrever em um arquivo sem apagar o que tem dentro dele? Estou usando as classes abaixo.

```
public void criarArquivos() throws IOException{

    /*1 forma*/
    FileWriter arqTeste = new FileWriter("teste.txt");
    PrintWriter gravaTeste = new PrintWriter(arqTeste);
    gravaTeste.println("Jesus is Perfect.");
    arqTeste.close();

    /*2 forma*/
    Formatter arquivo = new Formatter("teste2.txt");
    arquivo.format("Jesus is love, but Justice too.");
    arquivo.close();
}

public void lerArquivos() throws IOException{
    /*1 forma*/
    FileReader obter = new FileReader("teste.txt");
    BufferedReader receber = new BufferedReader(obter); //pq tem advertencia?

    String frase = receber.readLine();
    while(frase != null) {
        System.out.println(frase);
        frase = receber.readLine();
    }

    /*2 forma*/
    FileInputStream arq = new FileInputStream("teste2.txt");
    InputStreamReader ler = new InputStreamReader(arq);
    BufferedReader leitura = new BufferedReader(ler);   //pq tem advertencia?

    String linha = leitura.readLine();
    while(linha != null) {
        System.out.println(linha);
        linha = leitura.readLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Seu título da pergunta difere do conteúdo. Você quer adicionar um texto a um arquivo que já existe, isso?

Comment: Sim, tendo um arquivo que ja existe e ja possui um conteudo, quero escrever nele sem apagar o que ja tem escrito

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você deve instanciar o `FileWriter` com o parâmetro `true`, [veja](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java):

```
try(FileWriter fw = new FileWriter("outfilename", true);
    BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(fw);
    PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(bw))
{
    out.println("texto");
    out.println("outro texto");
} catch (IOException e) {
    // exceção
}
```

Isso fará com que o arquivo abra em modo `append`, ou seja, para adicionar dados e não sobrescrever.

Utilizar um buffer para escrever no arquivo é o mais indicado visto que operações de acesso ao disco são mais lentas.

Answer (score 1):

Uma das opções é criar um método onde você passará o caminho arquivo e o texto que será aplicado:

```
private void escrever(String caminho, String conteudo) throws IOException {
  Path arquivo;

  arquivo = Paths.get(caminho);
  Files.write(arquivo, conteudo.getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
}
```

[How to append text to an existing file in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625234/how-to-append-text-to-an-existing-file-in-java)

Answer (score 0):

Uma opção é usar a classe [Files](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html). Ficaria algo como:

```
    try {
        Files.write(Paths.get("C:/arquivo.txt"), "NOVO TEXTO".getBytes(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

O método `write` espera três parâmetros:

- path - o caminho do arquivo
- bytes - matriz de bytes com os bytes para escrever
- options - opção que espefífica como o arquivo é aberto. **Append** é sugestivo que irá adicionar, não sobrescrever.

Comment: Pode editar a resposta e explicar como esse código funciona?

Comment: Claro. Editado @diegofm